# How large must a body of water be?

Tags: pokemon-go

Nearby my work, there is a small (i assume man-made) pond/lake thing. I know it has been said by Niantic that water pokemon will spawn near water sources, but I'm wondering, how big do they need to be?

[image: Lake near my job]

I never get any water Pokemon near this body of water, save for when it rains heavily, and the occasional Tentacool appears (although finding it is another story...)

Comment: From personal experience I'm not certain if it's dependent on size and is more like what Niantic has flagged as a body of water. I say this because near me there is a very large reservoir but I haven't seen any water Pokemon near it, but a smaller one on the other side of town I have seen some.
Could very well be a fluke and you are correct about it being size dependent though.

Comment: Are you serious about the "when it rains" ? Could it be coincidence or do you have enough experimental data to be statistically relevant evidence? Or is it 'public knowledge' (I had never heard of it) that the actual weather influences the type of pokemon spawning?

Comment: @hertitu Well, I haven't played the game in a good couple of months now, so I don't have an answer for you there. But I would notice that consistently, after it rained, there would be more Tentacools around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's more than enough. There's a smaller man-made lake in a park near my house I caught some Magikarp.

Near my workplace there's a canal as wide as 10M, and the game indicates there are Magikarp and other water type near by.

As long as there's blue on the map, there's a chance you'll be getting water types.

Comment: Must be a slim to none chance then, I've never seen one unless it rains.